# "list index out of range" error within nested loop structure but not outside of it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

this is my first question here ever.

I'm trying to extract only the word forms from a text corpus and write them into a text file.

the **corpus** looks like this:

```
<corpus>
<text id="t0">
<s>
Computerlinguistik  NN  NOUN    Computerlinguistik
</s>
<s>
In  APPR    ADP In
der ART DET der
Computerlinguistik  NN  NOUN    Computerlinguistik
    _SP SPACE     
oder    KON CCONJ   oder
linguistischen  ADJA    ADJ linguistischen
Datenverarbeitung   NN  NOUN    Datenverarbeitung
...
</s>
...
```

So

1. A **sentence** is marked with *<s>...</s>*
2. The **words** of a sentence are split up into newlines
3. Each **line** has the **word form** (and some tab separated annotations, e.g. part of speech tag)

### My approach

To get to the word form my approach is:

> 1. Making a **list** with all the sentences without xml tags
> 2. Split each **sentence** of that list at '\n'
> 3. Split each **line** at any whit space character
> 4. Write the **first element** of that "line list" into a .txt file

### The issue

However, I'm getting an `list index out of range` error when trying to access the first element within the loop:

```
# getting the xml-like content:
soupWiki = BeautifulSoup(open('MeinWikiKorpus.vrt'))

# getting a list of all sentences (< s >...< /s >) without xml tags:
wikiSentences = [sentence.get_text() for sentence in soupWiki.find_all('s')]

for s in wikiSentences:
    # splitting each sentence by '\n'
    for line in (s.splitlines()):
        # splitting each line into it's elements (word form, POS-Tag, ...)
        lElements = line.split()
        print(lElements[0])
```

However, when I try to access the first element out side of all the loops, it works.

I'm sure it's just a silly mistake and by writing this question I might have figured it out already but some how I'm stuck here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing:

> ```
>         lElements = line.split()
> ```

There's a few things going on here.

1. Some lines are blank, so `.split()` finds zero elements.
2. We repeatedly assign to lElements -- it will retain final value after the loop is done.
3. Final line is non-blank.

Before de-referencing the 0th element
you will want to check with a guard.

Verbosely: `if len(lElements) > 0:`

Concisely:

```
        if lElements:
            print(lElements[0])
```

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks a lot!